# Showing missing sequence procedure won't work

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I post this question before, but I think the idea is missed up.
Here is my new explanation.

The following script should `DBMS_OUTPUT`, only the missing sequence.. But while I am testing it, I tried to delete a record. But this script still did not print that this sequence number is missing.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3c9e2/1/0

```
create or replace procedure show_missing_seqs(yy in varchar2 default '[0-9]{2}',
                                              mm in varchar2 default '[0-9]{2}',
                                              dd in varchar2 default '[0-9]{2}') as
  pattern varchar2(80);
  min_seq number(4):=1;
  max_seq number(4):=9999;
  cursor cur(pattern varchar2) is with 
  t as(
    select to_number(substr(filename, 5, 4)) as seq,
           substr(filename, 10, 2) as yy,
           substr(filename, 13, 2) as mm,
           substr(filename, 16, 2) as dd
      from test1@ra2013
     where regexp_like(filename, pattern)),
  r(yy, mm, dd, seq, max_seq) as(
    select yy, mm, dd, min_seq, max_seq
      from t
     group by yy, mm, dd
    union all
    select yy, mm, dd, seq + 1, max_seq
      from r
     where seq + 1 <= max_seq)
      select yy, mm, dd, seq as missing_seq
        from r
       where not exists (select 1
                from t
               where t.yy = r.yy
                 and t.mm = r.mm
                 and t.dd = r.dd
                 and t.seq = r.seq)
       order by yy, mm, dd, seq;


begin
  pattern := 'CDR[-][0-9]{4}[_][0-9]{2}' || yy || '[_][0-9]{2}' || mm ||
             '[_][0-9]{2}[_][0-9]{4}[_][N]["2"]';

  for rec in cur(pattern) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(rec.missing_seq);
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line('Done');

end show_missing_seqs;
```

Comment: Try changing the parameter names to something that doesn't conflict with column names in your queries - something like p_YY, p_MM, and p_DD would probably be good. Looking at your query, there's the potential for the compiler to make a wrong guess as to **which** yy, mm, or dd it should be using in various places. Share and enjoy.

Comment: That would be a more clear question if you show us your tables DDL by [Sqlfidle](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: You've linked to that Fiddle three times now but you still haven't said which sequence number value you think is missing from your example. The query doesn't match what you've shown above. I'm not sure this should find anything at the moment because you've changed the `pattern`, as I said before too. The `yy`, `mm`and `dd` *replace* the three `[0-9]{2}` sections from [your original query](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21847601/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you run a PLSQL script from SQLPLus, make sure you have serveroutput on to actually see what it prints to the output.

sql>set serveroutput on

Comment: I am using toad software and its on also notice that there is Done word will be print no mater what the result is to let me know that procedure has been finished

Answer (score 0):

You mean you are missing missing sequence from 510 to 4356?

By running your code exactly... I can see the output. It is printing all missing sequence until 509. You are not seeing after 509 because of union all operator. Union all is passing the last row from previous result (table t) into table r and hence missing seq until 509. To illustrate this I have explicitly called table t data into 2nd part of union all and also printed max_seq. from results you will see first two rows are from upper part of UNION ALL and rest are from 2nd part of UNION ALL and watch at max_seq column.

```
A   14  01  17  4356    4356    4356
A   14  02  07  397     509     509 
B   14  02  07  398     509     509 

with t as
( 
    SELECT
    to_number(substr(ename, 5,4 )) as seq,
    substr(ename, 10, 2) as yy,
    substr(ename, 13, 2) as mm,
    substr(ename, 16, 2) as dd
  from table1
  where regexp_like(ename, 'CDR[-][0-9]{4}[_][0-9]{2}[_][0-9]{2}[_][0-9]{2}[_][0-9]{4}[_][N]["2"]')
),
r (col, yy, mm, dd, seq, max_seq) as (
  SELECT 'A', yy, mm, dd, min(seq), max(seq)
  from t
  group by yy, mm, dd
  union all
  select 'B', yy, mm, dd,seq + 1, max_seq
  from r
  where seq + 1 <= (SELECT max(max_seq) FROM t)
)
select col, yy, mm, dd, seq, max_seq as missing_seq, max_seq
from r
```

Not Sure why you are using YY-MM-DD in comparison, but here's the sql I would have used If I want to mimic what you are doing - Only difference is t2, in which I ma making sure last row should be with the max-seq

```
with t as
    ( 
        SELECT
        to_number(substr(ename, 5,4 )) as seq,
        substr(ename, 10, 2) as yy,
        substr(ename, 13, 2) as mm,
        substr(ename, 16, 2) as dd
      from table1
      where regexp_like(ename, 'CDR[-][0-9]{4}[_][0-9]{2}[_][0-9]{2}[_][0-9]{2}[_][0-9]{4}[_][N]["2"]')
    ), t2 AS (
    select max(yy) yy, max(mm) mm, max(dd) dd, min(seq) seq, max(seq) max_seq from t ORDER BY 5 ASC 
    ),
    r (yy, mm, dd, seq, max_seq) as (
      select yy, mm, dd, (seq), (max_seq) from t2
      union all
      select yy, mm, dd,seq + 1, max_seq
      from r
      where seq + 1 <= max_seq
    )
    select yy, mm, dd, seq as missing_seq, max_seq
    from r
    where not exists (
      select 1 from t2 t
      where t.yy = r.yy
      and t.mm = r.mm
      and t.dd = r.dd
      and t.seq = r.seq
    )
    order by yy, mm, dd, seq
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: The `union all` is part of a recursive CTE. The `4356` record is for a different day, and it's broken down by day, so there shouldn't be anything reported between `509` and `4356` on the 2nd, and there is no range gap on the 1st. I think... this has been going on for a while and I'm still not sure I'm fully understanding *8-)

Comment: man I drop it a record from my table that meets conditions and should be print  it as missing but it doesnt at sqlfiddle link everything between 0058 to 0708 seqs are missing .. coz they are same day year btw the seqs is limited from 1 to 9999 and may reused many times for example 7-2-2014 the seqs may starts at 0301 to 0550 and then stooped then start at 8-2-2014 until it finished and restarts at same day and spotted at seqs numbers 0560 so for the first seqs loops everything under 0301 are missing and every thing above 0550 are miss for the day 7-2-2014 but not missing for the month 2

Comment: thats why I am using YY-MM-DD format and I think I have to use the HHMISS also to recognize the missing seqs if the loop seq starts and stopped  again at same day

Comment: for more explanation the example at sqlfiddle link the missing seqs for same month "2" should be everything under 0058 and everything between 0058 to 0218 then everything between 0281 and 0238 etc etc notice in some cases that 0218 could be from the second loop so its missing for the first one but not for the second loop  ...

Comment: you could find two 0218 seqs so seqs may looped for 2 or 3 time and at third loops did not reach the 0218 number ??? so How I am ganna recognize that loops looped for two or three times ? i think thats by using the time part at string 'CDR-0472_14_02_07_0708_N2.FCDR' the last 4 numbers at it 0708

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments about the possibility of the sequence cycling within a day, the query is getting more and more complicated but I *think* this is what you're looking for:

```
with t as
(
  select to_number(substr(ename, 5,4 )) as seq,
    to_date(substr(ename, 10, 2) || substr(ename, 13, 2)
      || substr(ename, 16, 2) || substr(ename, 19, 4), 'RRMMDDHH24MI')
      as cdr_time
  from table1
  where regexp_like(ename,
    'CDR[-][0-9]{4}[_][0-9]{2}[_][0-9]{2}[_][0-9]{2}[_][0-9]{4}[_][N]["2"]')
  order by substr(ename, 10, 13)
),
u as (
  select cdr_date, cdr_time,
    case when lag(seq) over (order by cdr_time) is null then seq
        when lag(seq) over (order by cdr_time) > seq then 0
        when trunc(lag(cdr_time) over (order by cdr_time)) != trunc(cdr_time)
          then mod(lag(seq) over (order by cdr_time) + 1, 10000)
        end as min_seq,
    case when lead(seq) over (order by cdr_time) is null then seq
        when lead(seq) over (order by cdr_time) < seq then 9999
        when trunc(lead(cdr_time) over (order by cdr_time)) != trunc(cdr_time)
          then seq
      end as max_seq
  from t
),
v as (
  select cdr_time as min_cdr_time,
    lead(cdr_time) over (order by cdr_time) as max_cdr_time,
    min_seq,
    lead(max_seq) over (order by cdr_time) as max_seq
  from u
  where min_seq is not null or max_seq is not null
),
w (min_cdr_time, max_cdr_time, seq, max_seq) as (
  select min_cdr_time, max_cdr_time, min_seq, max_seq
  from v
  where min_seq is not null
  union all
  select min_cdr_time, max_cdr_time, seq + 1, max_seq
  from w
  where seq + 1 <= max_seq
)
select to_char(min_cdr_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as cdr_date,
  to_char(seq, 'FM0000') as missing_seq
from w
where not exists (
    select 1
    from t
    where t.cdr_time between w.min_cdr_time and w.max_cdr_time
    and t.seq = w.seq
  )
order by min_cdr_time, seq;
```

All CTEs again; most could be subqueries but `w` is recursive so probably simpler to leave them all like this.

CTE 't' converts the `ename` to a date/time value and a sequence value; this is used to generate the ranges and also to check back later for missing values.

CTE `u` compares each record from `t` with the previous and next one, based on the generated `cdr_time`, to figure out when either the date has changed or the sequence has cycled. This is a little tricky especially when the two coincide, but from a little bit of testing I think this works.

CTE `v` is just compressing the results from `u` into a single record for each date/cycle block. (In the SQL Fiddle below this had to cast the two date values to date, which doesn't make sense; not sure if that is something to do with that environment, I didn't have a problem running it natively).

CTE `w` then generates all the sequence values within each of those data/cycle blocks, pretty much the same as the answer to your previous question did. And the final query looks for missing values within those ranges, again the same as before.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d6348/11) for a large block of CDRs with a few deleted to make missing values that should be reported. Just to make life easier I've generated one record per minute, but it'll work with wider gaps. I'm hitting CPU resource limits on the data you have in your current Fiddle, so you may have issues running it in your environment - depends how much data and how many gaps you have I think.

If you put this in a procedure and want to limit the output to a single day's gaps, you probably want to add the restriction in `u` but with a day either side; *and* also in `v` for just that day. Hopefully this gives you something you can adapt though.